# how to slice div into tiles using jquery

Tags: jquery, slider, slice

I am trying to implement some code in which i want to slice a div into number of tiles just like we see this in image slider in which image is sliced into tiles and then next image comes. I didnt find any guidance or tutorial which can guide me how to do it? Please provide any guidance or jsfiddle with your answer. 
One last thing after showing slicing animation I want the div again to join together. 
I want some thing like http://www.appdesignserved.co/gallery/Facebook-Wigdet-Concept/12718579 .
See the animation in the container div of the GIF image

Comment: Disclaimer: It's mine. https://github.com/DocAsarel/trncfrm Look into the code

Comment: thanks for your answer but could you please explain me how to achieve this?

Comment: Basically cut the div in parts, set the image as background and push it accordingly to the location in the wrapping div?

Comment: But I want it to be done with div only. I have edited my question.

Comment: but it is all in the link there are only divs and one in the final wrapper http://www.jqueryrain.com/?meVrqkfn